# android zxing barcode scanner force close on back button

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have succesfully got the barcode scanner to scan and open a new intent on succesfull scan. What is broken though is when I try and click the back button while in the scanner I get this error, instead of going back to my app:

```
09-13 18:36:28.540    4227-4227/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.StatisticsPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3660)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ActionbarMenu.onActivityResult(ActionbarMenu.java:76)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3656)
        ... 11 more
```

I implement my barcode scanner with this:

```
//get result value
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

       //retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();

            Log.d("scan" , scanContent);

            //launch async task for results
            String url = "myurl";


            new GetBeerDataFromUPCJSON(this).execute(url);

        }

        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
```

I just tried taking out the Log.d brought up in the comments and I got this error:

```
09-13 22:38:29.621    8588-8588/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@423db348 that was originally added here
        android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@423db348 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:468)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPreExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:52)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage.onCreate(BeerPage.java:100)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 22:38:29.912    8588-8588/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:784)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:476)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:182)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:328)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:311)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:74)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error is here: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message. at line Log.d("scan" , scanContent); i guess. It looks loke scanContent is empty.

Comment: @SimonSchubert just tried to take that line out and got more errors, I added them to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not from Barcode Scanner, which you can tell from your logs. It's your app that force closes. In fact in both cases the traces are pointing you right at the error.

First you printed something that was `null`:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ActionbarMenu.onActivityResult(ActionbarMenu.java:76)
    ...
```

Now you are holding on to a `Dialog` too long -- you can't do this across pause/resume. Search for this error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:784)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:476)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:182)
    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:328)
    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:311)
    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.GetBeerRateJSON.onPostExecute(GetBeerRateJSON.java:74)
```